# Get the website protocol when I have the address

Tags: url, web, network-protocols

So I have the address for a couple of sites like so `www.google.com` and nothing more, no protocol. Is it possible to know which protocol does the website use using any networking tools such as `curl` or `wget` or anything. I just need to know whether it uses `http` or `https`

Comment: maybe simply try to connect via `http` and then via `https` - e.g. a simple curl GET or OPTIONS should do it - then check the result - if you don't end up with connection error or timeout it probably means that protocol is used. Note they are not exclusive, depends on how the server is set up. Note also that protocols can be assigned to different ports than standard 80, respectively 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443
```

This assumes that the server you are testing is setup to use the standard https port `443`.

Answer (score 0):

www.google.com works both with http and https.

You can find out if site works with https by using rules from popular extension "HTTPS everywhere" https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/ (github source: https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/tree/master/src/chrome/content/rules). Using openssl s_client (see answer Tokozo Zane) can help too. Or you can send HEAD request and look at the location header: `curl -I -X HEAD http://ya.ru`